# Use the virtual environment created by my fresh install of Python3.6 on Google Cloud VM

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, virtualenv

I have a library that told me that my Python3.5 provided by my google cloud hosted virtual machine wassn't sufficient:

```
(scr_env) mikempc3@instance-1:~/scrapy-scraper$ scrapy crawl nosetime -a /pinpai/2-a.html
/home/mikempc3/scrapy-scraper/scr_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py:12: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.5 support will be dropped in the next release of cryptography. Please upgrade your Python.
  from cryptography import x509
Usage
=====
  scrapy crawl [options] <spider>

crawl: error: Invalid -a value, use -a NAME=VALUE
```

So I downloaded Python3.6.5 because it worked locally for the project I'm doing but I'm not yet able to use the virtual environment I created, necessary to run my scrapy scraper.

```
mikempc3@instance-1:~/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper$ virtualenv -p /tmp/Python36/Python-3.6.5 scr_env36
RuntimeError: failed to query /tmp/Python36/Python-3.6.5 with code 13 err: 'Permission denied'
mikempc3@instance-1:~/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper$ sudo virtualenv -p /tmp/Python36/Python-3.6.5 scr_env36
RuntimeError: failed to query /tmp/Python36/Python-3.6.5 with code 13 err: 'Permission denied'
mikempc3@instance-1:~/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper$ virtualenv mypython
created virtual environment CPython3.6.5.final.0-64 in 833ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/mikempc3/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper/mypython, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/mikempc3/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.2.4, setuptools==50.3.2, wheel==0.35.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
^C
mikempc3@instance-1:~/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper$ virtualenv tes_env
created virtual environment CPython3.6.5.final.0-64 in 161ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/mikempc3/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper/tes_env, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/mikempc3/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.2.4, setuptools==50.3.2, wheel==0.35.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
mikempc3@instance-1:~/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper$ tes_env/bin/activate
-bash: tes_env/bin/activate: Permission denied
mikempc3@instance-1:~/scrapy-scraper/nosetime_scraper$ sudo tes_env/bin/activate
sudo: tes_env/bin/activate: command not found
```

So how can I use the virtual environement created by my downloaded Python3.6

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is yet only a warning. But it would be useful to upgrade your python. Python is a so wonderful technology, that you only command a `pip upgrade` and everything will be done, automatically to the latest stable, with each other compatible versions, and everything will run seamlessly; you can even upgrade python 2.6 to 3.9 without any problem. <sub><sup><sup>(irony)</sup></sup></sub>

It is very unlikely that it would be caused by some virtualization thingy. Upgrade your python. Activate should not be called so.

The activate script can not be called in this way. The correct call is

```
. x/bin/activate
```

and not `x/bin/active`. The difference is that the correct version commands your current shell to execute the commands/settings in `x/bin/activate`. The bad version (without the `.`  prefix) starts a new shell, whose only task is to execute `x/bin/activate` as a script.

For the second, you need both read and execution access. For the first, you only need read access. This activate script, probably exactly on this reason, has no execution flag.

If a file has no execution flag, not even the root can execute it (but he can give +x for it on need). This is why it still did not work, even with sudo. (After a `chmod +x tes_env/bin/activate`, it had worked but the settings where applied in a subshell which exits after the command is run, so it had not done anything.)